# Is my program working how it should be?

Tags: python

**Information:**
I am working on a program for a new website I am developing which will be known as "Coinflip". In this program I have tried to use all the necessary things to ensure that the winner is fairly chosen. Is this fair? Have I gone wrong? Because I can't tell and it would help me for somebody who has never seen the program could tell me where I went wrong or if it is working as it should. Thank you for your kind help!

***Code:***

```
import random

invinp = True

def main():

    winnerprob = []

    invinp = False
    user1 = input("User 1, Please input your name\n")
    user2 = input("User 2, Please input your name\n")

    winnerprob.append(user1)
    winnerprob.append(user2)

    random.shuffle(winnerprob)

    user1 = random.choice(winnerprob)
    user2 = random.choice(winnerprob)

    winner = random.randint(0,100)

    if winner <50:
        print(user1 + " wins!")
    elif winner >50:
        print(user2 + " wins!")

    print("When you enter your username, User 1 and User 2 are shuffled randomly to ensure that both parties have an equal chance of winning.")
    print("If unchanged, User 1's position was shuffled to: " + user1)
    print("If unchanged, User 2's position was shuffled to: " + user2)
    print("Here are the probabilities:")
    print("User 1 = 0, 50\nUser 2 = 51, 100")
    print("The number that was randomly generated was: " + str(winner))

while invinp:
    main()
```

Comment: I understand this question may come along as breaking the rules, but this is a genuine question because I can't see if my program is doing as it should.

Comment: How are you planning to serve this as a website?

Comment: what if `winner == 50`?

Comment: Probability wise, this is the logic. 2 options, random float (0,1), if its >=0.5 the second one wins otherwise the first one. Logicwise it should be good (Don't forget to check the equality as well).

Comment: I noticed this as I asked the question, I said that User 1 is going to win if the number is 0, 50, so I made the if statement: "if winner <= 50" instead.

Comment: What have you done to test the program so far?  Why does that not lead you to at least a feeling of confidence about the outcomes?  Where is your test driver?

Comment: Please take this to the [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @user2357112 That's irrelevant, but I am planning how the code will work in Python then implementing a working version onto HTML

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in the http://codereview.stackexchange.com site.

Comment: Belongs on Code Review isn't a valid close reason @Prune

Comment: @Prune did you read my first comment? It is a question because I don't know if my program is doing as it should

Comment: Migration is a valid reason; CodeReview isn't on the list.  What do you recommend as the proper action, then?  I took this suggestion from a search on Meta.

Comment: @GregK. it makes more sense to use random.choice when you have a discreet number of options

Comment: Migration isn't a valid close reason @Prune, Migration is a closure effect. Try to close the question with an actual closure reason, for example: _Not asking about a specific problem_

Comment: @Matt, yes, I read your first comment.  Did you read mine?  From the lack of extra information, I infer that you don't know whether the program is running correctly because you haven't tested it.  I asked about test results.  Empirical data is generally a more reliable and faster starting point than eyeball inspection.

Comment: @Quill, that's not the impression I got last October (I looked for how to handle things that belong in CodeReview).  I have no problem with my closure vote dying for lack of a second; that's why a single vote can't close a question.

Comment: @Prune, Quill is quite correct in stating that code review (nor migration) are close reason for Stack Overflow. In addition please read a [Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Thanks; I haven't reviewed this one since I first encountered Code Review.  I found the critical portion about 1/3 way down.  Closure vote retracted; I can't re-vote to close, but I'll leave that up to others.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mostly fine, but it does more work than it needs to. Almost like flipping the coin three times to make sure it's extra random. This would be sufficient:

```
import random

invinp = True

def main():

    winnerprob = []

    invinp = False
    user1 = input("User 1, Please input your name\n")
    user2 = input("User 2, Please input your name\n")

    winner = random.randint(1,100)

    if winner <=50:
        print(user1 + " wins!")
    elif winner >50:
        print(user2 + " wins!")

    print("When you enter your username, User 1 and User 2 are shuffled randomly to ensure that both parties have an equal chance of winning.")
    print("If unchanged, User 1's position was shuffled to: " + user1)
    print("If unchanged, User 2's position was shuffled to: " + user2)
    print("Here are the probabilities:")
    print("User 1 = 0, 50\nUser 2 = 51, 100")
    print("The number that was randomly generated was: " + str(winner))

while invinp:
    main()
```

Comment: Okay, so I guess I was just doing more than what the whole purpose of the program is. Thank you. Really appreciate this.

Comment: `print (random.choice(["User1","User2"]) +" wins!")`